# How can I make Windows Task Manager keep it's position and size upon reopening?

Tags: windows, task-manager

When I open Windows Task Manager in Windows XP with SP3 it opens in the top left corner and it occupies a very small part of the screen. If I resize and reposition it to fill most of the screen when I open it again it loses the new position/size settings and it starts with the same position/size as the first start.

How can I make Windows Task Manager keep it's position/size settings upon reopening?

Comment: I don't know why yours doesn't, but all of my windows remember their position and size on my Windows XP box.  Check to see if you disabled it somehow (try TweakXP)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it maximized, then just enlarge by slowly dragging the edges/corners outward; Don't click the maximize button.

You also may be able to use [AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/); <strike>but as I haven't tried this, I can't confirm it.</strike>

EDIT: You may need to create a **shortcut** (C:\Windows\System32 then **right click** on **taskmgr**,click **Send to** > **Desktop (create shortcut)**) so that u can run the shortcut however you want ex. with the sizing you want.

Once on the desktop get to its **properties** (right click to get that to that button) > in the **Shortcut** tab click **Shortcut Key** then enter a key combo (and no, it can **not** be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Del</kbd>) then press OK or apply.

Comment: The program is pretty nice but it doesn't do exactly what I need. There should be a way to make Task Manager keep it's position and size settings.

Comment: Read the first part of my answer.  Doesn't that work? BTW it makes a difference how you launch task manager.  How are you launching it? just a simple <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd> Esc </kbd>?

Comment: I know how to ***resize*** it, I don't need that. Read the question again please.

Comment: read my comment.  HOW DO YOU OPEN TASK MANAGER?  Using keyboard shortcuts? Double clicking a shortcut? Right clicking on the taskbar?

Comment: I open it using CTRL + SHIFT + ESC.

Comment: You can't use a keyboard shortcut that is already taken.  Maybe you could use Ctrl + Shift + ` (button left of the no.1 key)

Comment: CTRL+ SHIFT + ESC opens Task Manager by default, you don't need to do any setting to open it.

Comment: your not trying to open task manager.  your (now) trying to open a shortcut to Task Manager, and the properties of that shortcut (ex. the box size) will save, (analogy, prob not true)>you can add parameters (or settings that go into effect once the program is opened.) a parameter on your shortcut won't for example effect a different user running the program directly. Do you understand what I'm saying? You need to make a shortcut, then make a key-press shortcut to quickly open the shortcut.

Comment: Yeah, I got what you said the first time, but you didn't state your assumption before. Anyway, I can't test it now since the problem was fixed after restarting. :) Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use Autohotkey scripts for this, but there is also a graphical utility which also uses Autohotkey in the background called [**WinSize2**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/).

[image]